# Upvote Youtube Comment With API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hello guys i was reading google youtube data api But i did not found any way to upvote or like the comment on video. anyone have any info on this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's safe to conclude this feature does not exist for the following reasons,

1. The otherwise thorough [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments) makes no mention of this feature. I highly doubt youtube/google would forget to document a feature.
2. This question has been asked several times before on SO; all of which have no accepted answer ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504392/upvote-downvote-a-comment-on-a-video-via-api), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339966/youtube-api-v3-rate-like-dislike-comment-commentthread), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135693/youtube-data-api-v3-like-comment-of-another-user)). With the oldest question being 10 months old, it's very unlikely no one would have found this feature if it did exist.
3. Youtube is a common target of [voter-bots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Votebots#Usual_Target) and hence it would make sense to not offer an API entry-point as a first line of defense.
4. The official [Youtube (android) app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube&hl=en) offers no comment-upvote option but only flag and reply options. If a comment-upvote feature would exist, you'd think Youtube would show it off in their own app.

Comment: Thank you for your replay Hope they will add this in future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can like a comment, but only if it is YOUR comment. That means if you were the author of it.

Sorry for the short answer, but that is all there is to it in v3