# Youtube Data API V3 - Like comments and commentThreads

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to like commentThreads and/or comments (replies) through the Python Youtube Data API?

It's not listed in the official API site, but neither is liking videos, and I've seen plenty of ways (and consequently bots) to do so. Thus I was wondering if by any means there is a workaround for my case as well.

---

OBS.: I'm creating a better way for me to handle my channel's comments, using Youtube's interface is not practical in my case. I don't, in any way, approve the use of bots to pollute the comments section. If you stumbled here trying to do so, please, f***ing don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not yet possible using the API. As referred in this SO post: [Youtube Data API v3: like comment of another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135693/youtube-data-api-v3-like-comment-of-another-user), this feature does not exist for the following reasons.

> The otherwise thorough API documentation makes no mention of this feature. I highly doubt youtube/google would forget to document a feature. This question has been asked several times before on SO; all of which have no accepted answer (1, 2, 3). With the oldest question being 10 months old, it's very unlikely no one would have found this feature if it did exist. Youtube is a common target of voter-bots and hence it would make sense to not offer an API entry-point as a first line of defense. The official Youtube (android) app offers no comment-upvote option but only flag and reply options. If a comment-upvote feature would exist, you'd think Youtube would show it off in their own app.

Hope this helps!